# How to clone a record with all children and grand children too?

Tags: visual-workflow

Hi i am using a flow to clone a record with children and grand children , but it cant be resolved by using flow ( governor limit).

Object A(current record) ---> object b(children) -----> object c(grand children).

Comment: Welcome to SFSE; Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. In particular, you need to demonstrate (use [edit]) the work you have done so far